# Need help making an if statement in php that creates a html href link when passed correctly

Tags: php, session, if-statement

```
<?php if ($_SESSION["isLoggedOn"] == True) {?>
<a href="termsConditions.php">LOGOUT</a>
<?php }?>
```

i want the link to only be created if the IF statement is successful and to not create it if it is not. At the moment no matter what i have tried to change the link will always be created. thanks.

Comment: What you've written should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
<?php
    if ($_SESSION["isLoggedOn"] == True)
    {
        echo '<a href="termsConditions.php">LOGOUT</a>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why would this work when his code doesn't? There's probably something else wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your this visible code seems to be corrected. May be you would have some error in storing the sessions. Try:

```
echo $_SESSION['isLoggedOn'];
```

OR try doing this:

```
<?php 

if ($_SESSION['isLoggedOn']) {
echo "<a href="#">Logout</a>";

}?>
```

Comment: Would be better to use `var_dump` instead of `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION["isLoggedOn"])  && $_SESSION["isLoggedOn"] == True) {?>
<a href="termsConditions.php">LOGOUT</a>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Yeah including `isset()` there is better but how will this help? `$_SESSION["isLoggedOn"]` is always set to `true` apparently. OP needs to look into how/where that value is getting set.

Comment: I think when user signin  isLoggedOn will be TRUE and other wise he is maintaining isLoggedOn as FALSE. So in this scenario isLoggedOn is not always set to TRUE

Comment: I am referring to the OP's question regarding `($_SESSION["isLoggedOn"] == True)` is always evaluating `true`. How is your answer (with exception of `isset()`) any different from the one in the question? The OP's code does not have any issues. As suggested in other answers the OP needs to debug on where that value is getting set.

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$_SESSION["isLoggedOn"]` is always TRUE.

Also dont use `== TRUE` for True/False variables.

Also logging out at terms and conditions page is not very good i guess ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Elaborate your code:

```
<?php 

session_start();

if ( !isset($_SESSION) || !isset($_SESSION["isLoggedOn"]) {
    echo "an error occured instantiating the session.";
    exit 1;
}

if ( $_SESSION["isLoggedOn"] === true ) {
     echo '<a href="termsConditions.php">LOGOUT</a>';
}

?>
```

1. You need to start a session as very first action in your PHP.
2. Check if you actually have a vale in $_SESSION
3. Then, check its state and output what you want.